# excel interop exception 0x8002000B

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

I have the following code to open a workbook and keep just one sheet:

```
//Get a new workbook.
oWB = app.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);

int len = oWB.Sheets.Count;

for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
{
    ((Worksheet)oWB.Sheets[i]).Delete();
}

oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
```

This code has worked for many years in many client configurations.

For some reason, I have a customer with excel 2013 (in Hebrew), and on his machine I get the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8002000B): Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets.get__Default(Object Index)
   at IOSIGHT.Win.ActiveReports.ExcelHelper.StartExcel()
```

If I understand the situation, it seems that for some reason the workbook was left with no sheets,
so then call to `oWb.ActiveSheet` throws an exception.
Any idea what caused this?

And yes I saw other posts on the same exception, but my code does not match their scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop backwards so you do not try to remove an index that no longer exists.

E.g `for (int i = len; i > 1; i--) ...`

Comment: +1 - Probably be `len - 1` and `i >= 1`, but its the right idea

Comment: The code worked fine for years because as long as there are less than 4 worksheets in the default workbook the bug is harmeless...